# proceeding with actual commit?

Tags: git, github

I'm in VIM, adding my commit message. Once I'm satisfied with my message, how do I proceed with the actual commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just exit from VIM.

type: ZZ in normal mode

Answer (score 2):

Save and quit VIM and it should all work like magic. You can also use `git commit -m "Message"` to avoid the need to start up your editor.